# Razor Syntax in Ajax.BeginForm Options

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to put my Model.ID into ajax helper like below

```
@model Modulerica13.Models.HrMapTrainingPerson

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("updateTrainingPerson", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "viewTrainingPerson",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "$('#editPersonModal').modal('hide')",

}
))
```

I want to add Model.ID while selecting DIV.

```
 OnSuccess = "$('#editPersonModal@(Model.Id)').modal('hide')",
```

I am getting sytnax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use razor syntax when you're already in the middle of a code block. You're into normal C# code here. Your current code is literally just going to put "@(Model.Id)" in the middle of the string.

```
OnSuccess = String.Format("$('#editPersonModal{0}').modal('hide')", Model.Id)
```

You also need to take the comma off the end of this line as it's the last property you're instantiating (this is why you're getting the error).

Answer (score 0):

You could change by this: `"$('#editPersonModal" + @Model.Id + "').modal('hide')"`.

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     window.doAfterSuccess = function(){
       var selector = "#editPersonModal" + @Model.Id;
       $(selector).modal('hide');
     }
   });
</script>
```

and have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("updateTrainingPerson", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "viewTrainingPerson",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "doAfterSuccess",

}
```